# Virtuemart is not working for multiple manufacturer

Tags: php, joomla, e-commerce, virtuemart

I am creating an E-commerce website using joomla2.5 and virtuemart2. When i am adding new product, i couldn't select multiple manufacturer for the product.

I don't know which file is exactly needed to hack the source code.

Here i have modified the html integration part in the location

administrator/components/com_virtuemart/views/product/tmpl/product_information.html at line 92

```
<?php if(isset($this->lists['manufacturers'])){?>
<tr class="row<?php echo $i?>">
<td width="21%" ><div style="text-align:right;font-weight:bold;">
<?php echo JText::_('COM_VIRTUEMART_MANUFACTURER'); echo'test-aaaaaaaaaa'; ?></div></td>
<td width="79%"><?php //echo $this->lists['manufacturers'];?>                       
<select class="inputbox" id="manufacturers" name="manufacturers[]" multiple="multiple" size="10">
<option value=""><?php echo $this->lists['manufacturers']; ?></option></select>                     </td></tr>
```

But i couldn't compute the manufacturer list from the database.i don't know which file to change the source code. Anybody knows please reply me!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this:

http://forum.virtuemart.net/index.php?topic=100170.0

I applied it into my virtuemart, and works as a charm.
I've got a bookshop to make.
I've added all authors as manufacterers and now with this change I can add multiple manufacterers (authors in my case) to one book, just like adding multiple categories.
I think its what you need.

Comment: yes, thats what i need! to have multiple manufacturer for a product.Please give some tips to do that.